# wpf how to bind to List

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i'm trying to bound a list of object to DataGrid but i'm getting wrong value:
the object class:

```
public class Attribute
{
    public Attribute()
    {

    }

    private string _name;

    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }



    private List<Value> _valueList = new List<Value>();

    public List<Value> ValueList
    {
        get { return _valueList; }
        set { _valueList = value; }
    }
}

public class Value
{

    private string _value;

    public string value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value.ToString();
    }
}
```

and i'm having a list of objects: `List<Attribute> attributes`

```
attributeDataGrid.ItemsSource = attributes;
```

when i bound i get a grid with name column correct
but the "ValueList" shown as "(Collection)" instead of the string...

how should i bound the List ?

Comment: can you add your xaml code (atleast datagrid part)...?

Answer (score 0):

Your overriden `ToString` method in `Value` is not called, because WPF displays the content of `ValueList` in your second column, i.e. it displays `ValueList.ToString()`.
What do you expect to see in the second column? A comma separated list of the values in the `ValueList`?

Comment: you are right, that's exactly the problem that the ToString() method is not called.
i would like to have it comma separated - what is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: You would need to write a converter that can convert `List<Value>` to `string`. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try below things it works for me.

On Load Method write below code

```
Attribute atr = new Attribute();
atr.ValueList.Add(new Value() { value = "One" });
atr.ValueList.Add(new Value() { value = "Two" });
atr.ValueList.Add(new Value() { value = "Three" });
atr.ValueList.Add(new Value() { value = "Four" });
dataGrid.DataContext = atr.ValueList;
```

On XAML file try below

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Hope this code snippet helps to you.